# New variables of function.

Tags: analysis

Let be $z=z(x,y)$ function of the independent variables $x$ and $y$. Given to the new variables $(u,v)$ subject

> $$x = u + \log v$$ $$y = v - \log u.$$

Express $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ in variables $(u,v)$.

What should I do first, I need hint ?

Comment: Have you heard of the Chain Rule?

Comment: you havent given z in terms of x and y

Comment: You can first use the Chain Rule to find expressions for $z_u$ and $z_v$, and then you can use these to solve for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$